# Query plan cache bloated by ad-hoc queries, even with "Optimize for Ad-hoc Workloads"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, execution-plan, plan-cache

I've been noticing what I thought to be unusual issues with our query plan cache, where the plans in the cache were never more than a day old.

Through running the following query (courtesy of [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/)), it showed that the majority of plans (4.5Gb of 6Gb cached plans or 44813 of ~50000), were Ad-hoc queries that had a use count of 1.

```
SELECT objtype AS [CacheType]
    , count_big(*) AS [Total Plans]
    , sum(cast(size_in_bytes as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs]
    , avg(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count]
    , sum(cast((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes ELSE 0 END) as decimal(18,2)))/1024/1024 AS [Total MBs - USE Count 1]
    , sum(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Plans - USE Count 1]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
GROUP BY objtype
ORDER BY [Total MBs - USE Count 1] DESC
```

I've determined the problem query (dynamic, with an `EXEC`, of course...), which is rather hideous, but also complicated to just 'fix', so I was looking into immediate improvements that could be made.

The instance is already set to use Optimize for Ad-hoc Workloads, however the `CacheObjType` from `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` are all **Compiled Plan** rather than **Compiled Plan Stub**.

When using the Ad-hoc Workload mode, should the plans not be **Compiled Plan Stub** until their `usecounts` are greater than 1? Or is that not how this works?

There's also a `refcounts` field that no one seems to refer to when talking about Adhoc queries. The refcounts is always 1 when the type is **Compiled Plan Stub** and 2 when type is **Compiled Plan**.  Even through reading [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187404.aspx), I'm not entirely sure what this field means. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), the second run of an ad hoc batch removes the stub (which was used only once) and creates and caches the plan (using it for the first time).

I also haven't seen many references to `refcounts` other than it being a count of references by cache objects. Adhoc Compiled Plan objects can still have a `refcount` of 1, so it's not exclusively caused by the persistence of the plan.

Comment: Just so I understand what you're saying, the usecount of 1 means the plan has been used once, however the query has been executed twice? A stub is therefore not converted into a plan, rather replaced by it?

Comment: From the link provided by @SQLFox - The compiled plan stub allows the Database Engine to recognize that this ad hoc batch has been compiled before but has only stored a compiled plan stub, so when this batch is invoked (compiled or executed) again, **the Database Engine compiles the batch, removes the compiled plan stub from the plan cache, and adds the full compiled plan to the plan cache**.